# flutter doctor --android-licenses and Error: Could not find or load main class [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I run `flutter doctor` and had an error

> Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
> 30.0.2) X Android license status unknown.

so I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` command and had this error Error:

> Could not find or load main class username\AppData\Local\Android\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\..

I am a beginner for flutter. please help me.